# addition quantity for dictionary with in list

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts, and I'd like to remove the dicts with identical key and value pairs.

For this list:

```
[ {
            "limit_price": 20.0,
            "pending_quantity": 2.0
        },
        {
            "limit_price": 80.0,
            "pending_quantity": 2.0
        },
        {
            "limit_price": 80.0,
            "pending_quantity": 2
        }
    ],
```

I'd like to return this:

```
{
        "limit_price": 20.0,
        "pending_quantity": 2.0
    },
    {
        "limit_price": 80.0,
        "pending_quantity": 4.0
    }
],
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
l = [
    {"limit_price": 20.0, "pending_quantity": 2.0}, 
    {"limit_price": 80.0, "pending_quantity": 2.0}, 
    {"limit_price": 80.0, "pending_quantity": 2}
]

import pandas as pd  

list(pd.DataFrame(l).groupby('limit_price').sum().reset_index().T.to_dict().values())
```

Result:

```
[{'limit_price': 20.0, 'pending_quantity': 2.0},
 {'limit_price': 80.0, 'pending_quantity': 4.0}]
```

Comment: works fine, possible  this answer get without using loop ??

Comment: Hi @Muthumani18, that is possible, I updated my answer. All the best.